# How to develop code for pre order and post order traversal in threaded binary tree?

Tags: c

In threaded binary tree it is possible for inorder traversal. But I'm asked for pre order and post order traversal in Threaded binary tree. I tried this code in single threaded binary tree. But i end up in errors. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you are having problems it is best to include information such as what you have already tried, why it didn't work, specific errors and a [minimal, complete and verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Hope this helps.

Comment: You can do it by recursion, but don't recurse down the threaded links.